# ruby when to eigenclasses come into existence

Tags: ruby, eigenclass

Do Eigenclasses exist prior to a singleton method being defined
on a Object or Class. ie Do they always exist or come in existence
when a singleton method or class method in defined?

Answer (score 6):

*Every* object *always* has a singleton class. Period. No ifs, no buts, no exceptions.

Depending on how clever the compiler or interpreter is, it may or may not perform some performance optimizations. But like all performance optimizations, those are not allowed to change the result of the program, so even if those performance optimizations *do* lead to certain states where a particular singleton class does *not actually* exist, the program still *must* behave as if it *did* exist, so you wouldn't be able to tell anyway. After all, that's pretty much the *definition* of "performance optimization".

Some Ruby implementations may do some optimizations, others may do other optimizations, some may even not do any optimizations *at all*. You can't tell from the result of your program, and you shouldn't care, you *mustn't* care.

For example, YARV performs the following optimizations:

- Since almost no object has singleton methods, creating a singleton class for *every* object would be a waste of memory, therefore singleton classes are created lazily: when you create a singleton method (`def foo.bar` or `Object#define_singleton_method`), when you open up the singleton class (`class << foo`), and when you ask for an object's singleton class (`Object#singleton_class`).
- Since almost every class has some sort of class method, the overhead of lazily creating a singleton class doesn't make sense, so for classes, the singleton class is always created eagerly.

But this is a private internal implementation detail of YARV. JRuby may do it differently. IronRuby may do it differently. MacRuby may do it differently. MRuby may do it differently. Topaz may do it differently. Rubinius may do it differently. MagLev may do it differently. Even the next patchlevel of YARV may do it differently.

If you look at the singleton class it's there. If you *don't* look at it, it doesn't matter whether it's there. So, semantically, it's always there.

Answer (score 0):

for objects like class, when a new class is created its eigenclass is also created, and of their object when they are created.

example:- creating a class

```
class User; end
```

or

```
User = Class.new
```

its eigenclass is also created at the same time,

and there a separate eigenclass is created for every object of User class